# How to remove a gap between navbar and container-fluid?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my case: http://codepen.io/gkos/pen/LxmrMP?editors=1100

```
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="navbar-text">Item</li>
        <li class="navbar-text">Item</li>
        <li class="navbar-text">Item</li>
        <li class="navbar-text">Item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="site-content container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 site-sidebar">
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="col-md-4"><p class="navbar-text">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><p class="navbar-text">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><p class="navbar-text">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

I have a navbar, a container-fluid with two collons. There is a gap between navbar and the container showed in blue (the body background-color), how can I remove it so that the columns background color fill from navbar to footer wihtout gaps? I know about margin colapsing but I can't find any margin bean applied....

Using negative margin in site-content class I could remove that gap, but I have to hardcode the gaps height in pixels and this seems not the right answer!

```
.site-content
  margin-top: -21px
```

Regards

Comment: `.navbar { margin-bottom: 0; }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysterious whitespace in between Bootstrap Navbar and row underneath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071306/mysterious-whitespace-in-between-bootstrap-navbar-and-row-underneath)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `navbar` class has a default `margin-bottom:20px` in the bootstrap css. You can override it by adding this:

```
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

**N.B.**: Make sure the above css property is below the bootstrap default css.

Comment: THAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANKS!

Comment: By the way, how can I check the bootstrap classes properties. Is there a kind of reference with all classes properties where I can search for properties or classes!?!

Comment: Sure I do, I just have to wait 6 minutes more, I don't know why but SS don't let me accept the answer before 8 minutes after the question is posted...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the navbar class, it adds a bottom margin of 20px, 
use need to make that margin-bottom in .nav bar as 0